# Segmentation faults upon running larger programs after a period of machine learning training

Tags: mac, memory, crash, memtest

Recently, I've been learning machine learning models and neural nets on my [iMac](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMac). However, now whenever I start a more intensive application (e.g. iTunes or JetBrains' [PyCharm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyCharm)), I get the following error message,

> [Application] quit unexpectedly

**Did I cook my CPU or RAM, or is this a "solvable problem"? If yes, what are my options?**

```
Process: Python [88435] Path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python Identifier: Python Version: 3.7.0a2 (3.7.0a2) Code Type: X86-64 (Native) Parent Process: pycharm [85805] Responsible: Python [88435] User ID: 501

Date/Time: 2020-10-31 11:18:40.488 -0700 OS Version: Mac OS X 10.13.6 (17G14019) Report Version: 12 Anonymous UUID: 10E17EB7-D94F-766C-D938-244298E6C211

Sleep/Wake UUID: 78288C12-9340-475C-8CAC-32A364829ADE

Time Awake Since Boot: 910000 seconds Time Since Wake: 19000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread: 0 Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV) Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000 Exception Note: EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb Terminating Process: exc handler [0]

VM Regions Near 0:

__TEXT                 0000000100000000-0000000100001000 [    4K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread 0 pydevd_cython_darwin_37_64.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x0000000107312c28 __pyx_pymod_exec_pydevd_cython_darwin_37_64 + 25304 1 org.python.python 0x00000001007bb93e PyModule_ExecDef + 302 2 org.python.python 0x000000010086c558 _imp_exec_dynamic + 104 3 org.python.python 0x0000000100775fc6 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 854 4 org.python.python 0x0000000100776051 PyCFunction_Call + 49 5 org.python.python 0x000000010084c985 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 32565 6 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 7 org.python.python 0x00000001007754fa _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 218 8 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 9 org.python.python 0x000000010084c001 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30129 10 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 11 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 12 org.python.python 0x00000001008489e2 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 16274 13 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 14 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 15 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 16 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 17 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 18 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 19 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 20 org.python.python 0x0000000100775819 PyFunction_FastCallDict + 633 21 org.python.python 0x0000000100777390 object_vacall + 208 22 org.python.python 0x0000000100777588 PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 184 23 org.python.python 0x000000010086e2ad PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 973 24 org.python.python 0x0000000100841343 builtin___import + 131 25 org.python.python 0x0000000100776e2a _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallKeywords + 954 26 org.python.python 0x0000000100776e81 _PyCFunction_FastCallKeywords + 49 27 org.python.python 0x000000010084452a call_function + 762 28 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 29 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 30 org.python.python 0x0000000100843fa4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100 31 org.python.python 0x0000000100840b5f builtin_exec + 639 32 org.python.python 0x0000000100775e89 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 537 33 org.python.python 0x0000000100776051 PyCFunction_Call + 49 34 org.python.python 0x000000010084c985 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 32565 35 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 36 org.python.python 0x00000001007754fa _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 218 37 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 38 org.python.python 0x000000010084c001 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30129 39 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 40 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 41 org.python.python 0x00000001008489e2 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 16274 42 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 43 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 44 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 45 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 46 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 47 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 48 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 49 org.python.python 0x0000000100775819 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 633 50 org.python.python 0x0000000100777390 object_vacall + 208 51 org.python.python 0x0000000100777588 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 184 52 org.python.python 0x000000010086e2ad PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 973 53 org.python.python 0x000000010084dacd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 36989 54 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 55 org.python.python 0x0000000100843fa4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100 56 org.python.python 0x0000000100840b5f builtin_exec + 639 57 org.python.python 0x0000000100775e89 _PyMethodDef_RawFastCallDict + 537 58 org.python.python 0x0000000100776051 PyCFunction_Call + 49 59 org.python.python 0x000000010084c985 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 32565 60 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 61 org.python.python 0x00000001007754fa _PyFunction_FastCallKeywords + 218 62 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 63 org.python.python 0x000000010084c001 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 30129 64 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 65 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 66 org.python.python 0x00000001008489e2 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 16274 67 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 68 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 69 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 70 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 71 org.python.python 0x00000001008444cf call_function + 671 72 org.python.python 0x0000000100849ca9 _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 21081 73 org.python.python 0x0000000100775357 function_code_fastcall + 135 74 org.python.python 0x0000000100775819 _PyFunction_FastCallDict + 633 75 org.python.python 0x0000000100777390 object_vacall + 208 76 org.python.python 0x0000000100777588 _PyObject_CallMethodIdObjArgs + 184 77 org.python.python 0x000000010086e2ad PyImport_ImportModuleLevelObject + 973 78 org.python.python 0x000000010084dacd _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault + 36989 79 org.python.python 0x0000000100843de8 _PyEval_EvalCodeWithName + 3080 80 org.python.python 0x0000000100843fa4 PyEval_EvalCode + 100 81 org.python.python 0x000000010088378e PyRun_FileExFlags + 206 82 org.python.python 0x0000000100883a2f PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags + 447 83 org.python.python 0x000000010089dcf0 Py_Main + 4240 84 org.python.python 0x0000000100000de8 0x100000000 + 3560 85 org.python.python 0x0000000100000c04 0x100000000 + 3076

Thread 0 crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit): rax: 0x0000000000000000 rbx: 0x0000000106eaaeb0 rcx: 0x0000000000000000 rdx: 0x0000000000000000 rdi: 0x0000000106ea1f48 rsi: 0x0000000104048200 rbp: 0x00007fff5bffa240 rsp: 0x00007fff5bffa0d0 r8: 0x0000000000000080 r9: 0x0000000104048228 r10: 0x0000000000000000 r11: 0x00000001007c0cb0 r12: 0x0000000107371ff0 r13: 0x00000001009994e0 r14: 0x0000000107371ff0 r15: 0x0000000101b2a270 rip: 0x0000000107312c28 rfl: 0x0000000000010206 cr2: 0x0000000000000000

Logical CPU: 2 Error Code: 0x00000004 Trap Number: 14

Binary Images: 0x100000000 - 0x100000ff7 +org.python.python (3.7.0a2 - 3.7.0a2) <5A77248E-3AD9-079E-E339-6CAC76C21FCB> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python 0x100003000 - 0x10049ffff com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.9 - 1455.300) /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation 0x100752000 - 0x100980fff +org.python.python (3.7.0a2, [c] 2001-2017 Python Software Foundation. - 3.7.0a2) <6C022B74-BAE7-EBDA-7329-27EE02F1A0B7> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/Python 0x100ad1000 - 0x100ad2ffb libSystem.B.dylib (1252.50.4) /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib 0x100ad9000 - 0x100adaff3 libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib (104) <3F855622-352B-3EA8-B7C8-94D1DB48C080> /usr/lib/libDiagnosticMessagesClient.dylib 0x100ae0000 - 0x100d07ffb libicucore.A.dylib (59181.0.1) <17767680-09DF-3954-AB6C-B13B41F92A2E> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib 0x100dd9000 - 0x1011ca3b7 libobjc.A.dylib (723) <616AB826-9179-3924-AA61-AF760363A3F5> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib 0x10137b000 - 0x10138dffb libz.1.dylib (70) <47278BDC-596E-3037-B8DA-05FE9D5DBEF6> /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib 0x101393000 - 0x101397ff7 libcache.dylib (80) <096D3699-58D2-3D23-9512-BC88DAE7B16C> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib 0x10139d000 - 0x1013a7ff3 libcommonCrypto.dylib (60118.50.1) /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib 0x1013b5000 - 0x1013bcfff libcompiler_rt.dylib (62) <4CEED002-D00B-35F8-B563-0546A5F71A43> /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib 0x1013ca000 - 0x1013d3ffb libcopyfile.dylib (146.50.5) /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib 0x1013da000 - 0x10145fffb libcorecrypto.dylib (562.70.3) <9C6E5CC2-272B-3740-AEDB-9EBEC98EC7F9> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib 0x10147c000 - 0x1014b5ff7 libdispatch.dylib (913.60.3) <285526B6-A2A6-316D-A1CC-37803B71E203> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib 0x1014f0000 - 0x10150dff7 libdyld.dylib (551.5) <49ABA86D-DD48-3133-9B14-B9A564EEBC66> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib 0x101528000 - 0x101528ffb libkeymgr.dylib (28) <7CC7B5E1-AB7F-3495-A26A-396461BCB66B> /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib 0x10152d000 - 0x10152dff7 liblaunch.dylib (1205.70.16) <265EE555-E988-3EE5-A39E-028FB3A5FE11> /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib 0x101534000 - 0x101538ffb libmacho.dylib (906) /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib 0x10153f000 - 0x101541fff libquarantine.dylib (86.70.1) <262CECFE-A493-3EC6-8608-CEA93757265E> /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib 0x101547000 - 0x101548ff3 libremovefile.dylib (45) /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib 0x10154e000 - 0x101565fff libsystem_asl.dylib (356.70.1) <9481D82D-CFB7-3032-A07F-88F7F59CAC2C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib 0x101573000 - 0x101573fff libsystem_blocks.dylib (67) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib 0x101578000 - 0x101601ff7 libsystem_c.dylib (1244.50.9) <25DD83D8-80CA-3DFF-8626-FE704911F19C> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib 0x10162a000 - 0x10162dffb libsystem_configuration.dylib (963.50.9) <61B26E1D-FEFF-38C6-AE0E-A6DD90145EB2> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_configuration.dylib 0x101634000 - 0x101637ffb libsystem_coreservices.dylib (51) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_coreservices.dylib 0x10163d000 - 0x10163efff libsystem_darwin.dylib (1244.50.9) <6195EEA1-83A7-35F0-8147-5AB031020CD0> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib 0x101644000 - 0x10164affb libsystem_dnssd.dylib (878.70.4) <0D2C9583-5D28-375B-AEB4-F66F18C78322> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib 0x101651000 - 0x10169aff7 libsystem_info.dylib (517.30.1) <9C2C96F3-638B-34E7-A2BD-24C643EAF957> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib 0x1016b2000 - 0x1016fdfcb libsystem_m.dylib (3147.50.1) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_m.dylib 0x10170c000 - 0x10172bff7 libsystem_malloc.dylib (140.50.7) <821E16C8-7A7E-3269-9167-10F4F413BF93> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib 0x101738000 - 0x101868ff7 libsystem_network.dylib (1229.70.2) <07BFD80A-E7EB-3DEB-B765-5E1659453114> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib 0x1018a9000 - 0x1018b3ffb libsystem_networkextension.dylib (767.70.2) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_networkextension.dylib 0x1018c0000 - 0x1018c9ff3 libsystem_notify.dylib (172) <738B3BB0-4F20-3446-A3B6-095D796E5903> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib 0x1018d1000 - 0x1018d4fff libsystem_sandbox.dylib (765.70.1) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib 0x1018db000 - 0x1018dcff3 libsystem_secinit.dylib (30) <4E84DF62-57B5-36F9-819F-3C1E7FEDA856> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_secinit.dylib 0x1018e2000 - 0x101908ff7 libsystem_kernel.dylib (4570.71.82.5) <999FCB9D-CBCD-317D-A2ED-034B6D7FB23A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x101922000 - 0x101929ff7 libsystem_platform.dylib (161.50.1) <90A2A62F-8690-3FA7-A4D0-9085BF2FA44A> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib 0x101932000 - 0x10193dfff libsystem_pthread.dylib (301.50.1) <283E64A7-A2B2-3212-95BA-4D21F9AE36CF> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x10194a000 - 0x101951ff7 libsystem_symptoms.dylib (820.60.3) /usr/lib/system/libsystem_symptoms.dylib 0x101958000 - 0x10196cff7 libsystem_trace.dylib (829.70.2) <4C4E5351-E370-3226-9B30-61E250DE3B2E> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib 0x10197b000 - 0x101980ff7 libunwind.dylib (35.3) /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib 0x101988000 - 0x1019b5fff libxpc.dylib (1205.70.16) <26D99819-B813-320E-9E8F-9D57AD2DA63B> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib 0x1019d8000 - 0x101a0bff7 libclosured.dylib (551.5) <112BC241-6626-3848-8DD8-B34B5B6F7ABC> /usr/lib/closure/libclosured.dylib 0x101a27000 - 0x101a4bff7 libc++abi.dylib (400.8.2) /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib 0x101a5b000 - 0x101ab1fff libc++.1.dylib (400.9) <142D6292-F30F-3949-9F37-3C97A579F540> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib 0x101be8000 - 0x101be9fff +_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <53FB6C57-4292-B8A4-5F6F-F9C58C145801> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x101bed000 - 0x101bedfff +_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_opcode.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x101bf1000 - 0x101bf2fff +_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x101bf5000 - 0x101bf8ff7 +select.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <5A3CAB3B-4565-36A3-F00F-74BDB12517A6> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/select.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104ae0000 - 0x104ae5fef +math.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <7B5CA904-BC4F-505A-6CF3-65F918B98266> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/math.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104aec000 - 0x104af1fff +_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <75417590-B0A8-C873-8AFD-6E88C078026B> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104afa000 - 0x104afafff +_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <44D00227-ECC4-3AFB-125D-A8F3EA49AEE0> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bisect.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104afd000 - 0x104afdfff +grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <7D158058-E0F2-3A5A-6023-BED77F851EEC> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/grp.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104ce5000 - 0x104cefff7 +_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <9AE748DF-3592-5EBB-7460-887580283673> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_socket.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x104cfb000 - 0x104cfcfff +_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_random.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x1068c9000 - 0x1068ccff7 +binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/binascii.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x1068d0000 - 0x1068dffff +_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_datetime.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x1068ea000 - 0x106932fff +_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <312C883D-5D61-65E4-C997-1BFF873B8535> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_decimal.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106951000 - 0x106954ff7 +_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <7C7990D3-3EA9-DABD-7ED3-EE38273747EA> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_hashlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106959000 - 0x1069affe7 +libssl.1.0.0.dylib (1) <0B00B469-F396-2A52-7BCD-C868035895A9> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib 0x1069cb000 - 0x106b96f67 +libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (1) <093F2A08-4047-4F8B-7A3C-C3FC29D67A18> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib 0x106c0d000 - 0x106c16fff +_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <7C0F0D03-E6EF-DF7F-AA2D-EA7B1755C6DB> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_blake2.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106c1b000 - 0x106c2efff +_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sha3.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106c34000 - 0x106c42fff +_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <480CFD08-4479-7D38-D04A-85C558211F3E> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106c52000 - 0x106c88fef +pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <330F6AA9-6255-9850-B723-49571D742CED> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/pyexpat.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106c9b000 - 0x106c9ffff +zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/zlib.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106d25000 - 0x106d26fff +_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_bz2.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106d2a000 - 0x106d37ffb libbz2.1.0.dylib (38) <0B4321CD-3D6F-3095-A12E-27F66B4321AD> /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib 0x106d3d000 - 0x106d69fe7 +_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_lzma.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106e73000 - 0x106e74ff7 +fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106eb8000 - 0x106eceff7 +_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106f70000 - 0x106f76ff7 +_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) <2C9627B2-220F-7521-BDAF-D35ACC43580A> /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_json.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x106fbb000 - 0x106fcdff7 +_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so (???) /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_pickle.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x10730c000 - 0x107376fff +pydevd_cython_darwin_37_64.cpython-37m-darwin.so (0) /Users/USER/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/*/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydevd_bundle/pydevd_cython_darwin_37_64.cpython-37m-darwin.so 0x7fff5e773000 - 0x7fff5e7bdadf dyld (551.5) /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary: Calls made by other processes targeting this process: task_for_pid: 3 thread_create: 0 thread_set_state: 0 Calls made by this process: task_for_pid: 0 thread_create: 0 thread_set_state: 0 Calls made by all processes on this machine: task_for_pid: 214688170 thread_create: 0 thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary: ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=27.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=27.9M(100%) Writable regions: Total=99.6M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=99.6M(100%)

                            VIRTUAL   REGION
REGION TYPE SIZE COUNT (non-coalesced) =========== ======= ======= Kernel Alloc Once 8K 2 MALLOC 83.0M 23 MALLOC guard page 16K 5 MALLOC_LARGE (reserved) 128K 2 reserved VM address space (unallocated) VM_ALLOCATE 4K 2 __DATA 4816K 93 __DATA_CONST 16K 2 __LINKEDIT 5876K 76 __TEXT 22.2M 76 __UNICODE 560K 2 __UNIXSTACK 16.0M 3 shared memory 12K 4 =========== ======= ======= TOTAL 132.4M 278 TOTAL, minus reserved VM space 132.2M 278

Model: iMac11,1, BootROM 63.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.8 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 1.54f36 Graphics: ATI Radeon HD 4850, ATI Radeon HD 4850, PCIe Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E4D3136464B44 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x859B, 0x435434473353313036374D2E4D3136464B44 Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 4 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x029E, 0x434D534F344758334D314131333333433920 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x8F), Atheros 9280: 4.0.74.0-P2P Bluetooth: Version 6.0.7f22, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports Network Service: Ethernet Airport, Ethernet, en0 Network Service: FireWire, FireWire, fw0 Serial ATA Device: WDC WD40EZRZ-19GXCB0, 4 TB Serial ATA Device: OPTIARC DVD RW AD-5680H USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: Keyboard Hub USB Device: Apple Keyboard USB Device: IR Receiver USB Device: Built-in iSight USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus USB Device: Hub USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader USB Device: BRCM2046 Hub USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller FireWire Device: unknown_device, Unknown FireWire Device: Macintosh, Apple Computer, Inc., Up to 800 Mb/sec Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Comment: I would definitely expect a  blue screen of death if my RAM or CPU were damaged, not just one or two programs crashing.

Comment: @QuoraFeans: Random segfaults that happen especially when the CPU is under heavy load (higher temperature) do tend to be a sign of overclocking just a little too much (or RAM or maybe CPU that's marginal and on the verge of failing.)  Often most of the CPUs time spent under these conditions is spent running user-space, not kernel code, so seeing programs crash without usually crashing the OS is actually not that rare for failing RAM.  especially if RAM is failing in a way that has 1 bad bit at a fixed location that the OS happens not to use for its own code/data.

Comment: @PeterCordes is there a way you know of to monitor a machine for failing ram? I use DriveDX for monitoring about 8 of my HDD but I've not seen a tool for failing RAM.

Comment: @CoffeeBaconAddict: HDDs have error-correction codes for each sector, and a controller (often a full ARM processor or similar) that makes it possible to run self-monitoring stuff (SMART).  DRAM is much simpler, and unless you have ECC RAM, doesn't have a way for the memory controller to detect errors.  (If you *do* have ECC RAM, errors can raise machine-check exceptions that software can catch, and can monitor corrected errors)  You can run memory tests manually if you suspect failing RAM, though, e.g. `memtest86+`, whether you have ECC RAM or not.

Comment: e.g. [How to tell whether RAM ECC is working?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/139319) mentions memtest86+ and its extra features for ECC RAM.  Also [How to monitor RAM ECC errors on Ivy Bridge Xeon E3 processor in Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/67999) covers some of the EDAC (error detection and correction) monitoring features.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's not an error message, that's a crash report. That particular crash report says the system forced an instance of Python to quit because Python illegally tried to access memory address zero. That's a common programming mistake usually caused by dereferencing a null pointer. Make sure your Python 3 environment is fully up to date in case this was a known problem with some version of Python that has since been fixed.

Your other crashes might be completely different, so this one crash log doesn't give us much to go on. Dereferencing zero is such a common kind of crashing bug that it's hard to see this as evidence of an overheated or damaged CPU, GPU, or RAM.

Comment: The error report gives the Python version as [3.7.0a2](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-370a2/) which is an Alpha version (definitely needs updating !).  This is the [python.org page for OSX releases](https://www.python.org/downloads/mac-osx/) - 3.9.0 is the latest (stable) release.

Comment: It's worth noting that machine learning frameworks tend to call out from Python into "native code", and in the case of the latter a simple programming mistake (or potentially even improper use given unsafe semantics) can cause exactly this kind of crash.

Comment: @StephenG The project uses multiple versions of python 3.7, 3.6, 3.2, code all the way back to Python 2.7 as some tools that I need were written back then. So while I'm still learning full-stack, my VM options are to stick with multiples of them until I can write good enough code to update it. Or if my startup gets funding or develops cash flow then I'll hire some Pythonista to rewrite it for me.

Comment: @CoffeeBaconAddict Using multiple *stable* release versions is bad enough, but using any  *alpha* version (unstable) is just asking for trouble.  You really need to update the 3.7.0a2 to a stable non-alpha release.

Comment: @StephenG I agree with what your saying, yet I don't really have an alternative right now. I pivoted in my career from finance to learning the math behind data science principles like Markov chains and Monte Carlo simulations for data analysis. While my model exceeds what is currently available in the market, coding is not yet my best asset. So I get great advice from people like you on SO and read lots of books to get better.

When you say "update the 3.7.0a2 to a stable nonalpha release" what does that mean? Load 3.6 or?

Comment: @CoffeeBaconAddict The general rule for upgrading to maintain stability (which is what you want here) is to make the minimum version number upgrade, so in this case from the (pre-release) alpha build (a2) to the first stable release after that (should be 3.7.0).  That version would have the absolute minimum bug fixes found during alpha and beta testing without any significant changes that might be incompatible with code that needs 3.7 compatibility.  If possible try all your code under a stable version like 3.7.0 or later and see if it works.

Comment: @CoffeeBaconAddict as you want to use different versions of python on OSX at the same time, I'd suggest looking at [this post on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36968425/how-can-i-install-multiple-versions-of-python-on-latest-os-x-and-use-them-in-par).  The main issue is that code for 2.7 and 3.x will often be incompatible so it is usual to just be using one 2.7 version and one 3.x version at the same time, not so much multiple versions.